# Does the weight option in coxph function fit the weighted cox regression model?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

Suppose I have a survival data with the variables `time`: follow up time, `event`: event indicator(1 or 0) with 1 as an event and 0 as censored, `treatment`: treatment group (0 or 1) and covariates `X1`, `X2`, `X3` AND `X4`.

First, I fit a logistic regression model to obtain the propensity scores. The outcome of logistic regression model is `treament` and `X1`, `X2`, `X3` AND `X4` are the predictors and obtain the propensity scores `ps` for each observations. Then, using inverse probability weighting, the weights `wt` are obtained as
`treatment/ps + (1-treatment)/(1-ps).`

Now, I want to fit a Cox proportional hazards regression model with these weights as follows:

`model1 <- coxph(Surv(time,event) ~ treatment + X1 + X2 + X3 + X4, weights=wt)`.

Is model1 same as $\lambda(t|treatment,X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)=wt*\lambda_0(t)* e^{\gamma *treatment+\beta_1*X_1+\beta_2*X_2+\beta_3*X_3+\beta_4*X_4}$ where $\lambda_0(t)$ is the baseline hazard function? What is the interpretation of adding these weights? Am I fitting weighted Cox proportional hazards regression model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, using the weights gives you a weighted estimator rather than a weighted model. The model is still
$$\lambda(t,z)=\lambda_0(t)e^{z\beta}$$
but instead of estimating it by maximising the log partial likelihood you estimate it by maximising a weighted log partial likelihood. The contribution of observation $i$ to the log partial likelihood is multiplied by the weight $w_i$.

The resulting estimates of $\beta$ and $\lambda$ are the same as if you had $w_i$ identical copies of observation $i$ (except that $w_i$ doesn't have to be an integer), though the standard errors are not the same as if you had multiple identical copies.

Comment: Does the weight w_i need to be multiplied by log likelihood or can it be multiplied by the likelihood and then take the logarithm? Would it make a difference? Is there any paper that I can refer to that talks about this situation?

Comment: It would make a huge difference. It needs to be the log likelihood. The original paper is https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/79/1/139/285631