# Handling ties in Cox regression using Peto-Breslow method, is the derivative of the log likelihood correct here?

Tags: r, survival, biostatistics, bioinformatics, actuarial-science

I am trying to implement Cox proportional hazard model in Python. Although, I know how to calculate the derivates of the Log likelihood, in the case of ties the likelihood function is modified. So I have two queries$$ l'(B) = \sum_j \delta_j * [s_j - d_j * \frac{\sum_{k\in R(Tj)} x_k e^{x_k*B}}{\sum_{k\in R(Tj)} e^{x_k*B}}] $$

where s_j is the sum of covariates

Is this log likelihood derivative wrt B correct for Peto-Breslow handling of ties?

Can someone explain me the Efron method and how its Likelihood function looks like? Also its  two derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Section 5.1 of the main R [survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf) explains the handling of ties in Cox models. The problem with tied event times is illustrated by the denominator in your formula:

$$ \sum_{k\in R(Tj)} e^{x_k*B},$$

which is the summed estimated risks of all those at risk at time $T_j$. With ties, it's not clear which individuals to include in that at-risk group for each of the events at that time. The vignette explains:

> The Breslow approximation ... in essence ignores the ties. If two subjects A and B died on day 100, say, the partial likelihood will have separate terms for the two deaths. Subject A will be at risk for the death that happened to B, and B will be at risk for the death that happened to A. In life this is not technically possible of course: whoever died first will not be at risk for the second death.

So the Breslow approximation just solves the standard partial-likelihood score function that you display. It ignores the technical impossibility of all individuals with an event at $T_j$ being in the risk set for all those events.

The Efron approximation instead uses an *average* of the possible denominators in your formula. The vignette starts with the case of two cases with the same event time, and expands from there:

> the Efron approximation is to use the average of the two [possible denominators] as the denominator term. In the software this is easily done by using temporary case weights: if there were $k$ tied events then one of the denominators gives each of those $k$ subjects a weight of 1, then next gives each a weight of $(k − 1)/k$, then next a weight of $(k −2)/k$, etc.

[This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/538876/28500) describes how to incorporate weights into the partial likelihood for a Cox model. To check your work, I think that the Python [`lifelines` package](https://pypi.org/project/lifelines/) uses the Efron method as the default for handling ties.